# R: Restart counter per group appearance

Tags: r, group-by, restart

I read a lot and tested a lot but no success.
I'm looking to created a counter per group but this coutner to restart everytime a group appears (even if it "reappears").

Example:

I need a seq_along per `TYPE_OF_PROMOTION` that restart per group appearance.
The result should be like `counter`
Since promo B reappears in Week 18 but is a new appearance - restart the counter.

If the solution works for NAs as well - ok, I just made a quick demo.

```
   Week TYPE_OF_PROMOTION counter
11   11              <NA>      NA
12   12                 B       1
13   13                 B       2
14   14                 B       3
15   15              <NA>      NA
16   16              <NA>      NA
17   17              <NA>      NA
18   18                 B       1
19   19                 B       2
20   20              <NA>      NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the run-length-id of 'TYPE_OF_PROMOTION', create the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`) multiplied by those having `NA` in 'TYPE_OF_PROMOTION' to create the 'counter' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, counter2 := seq_len(.N) * NA^is.na(TYPE_OF_PROMOTION), 
      by = rleid(TYPE_OF_PROMOTION)]
df1
#    Week TYPE_OF_PROMOTION counter counter2
# 1:   11              <NA>      NA       NA
# 2:   12                 B       1        1
# 3:   13                 B       2        2
# 4:   14                 B       3        3
# 5:   15              <NA>      NA       NA
# 6:   16              <NA>      NA       NA
# 7:   17              <NA>      NA       NA
# 8:   18                 B       1        1
# 9:   19                 B       2        2
#10:   20              <NA>      NA       NA
```

---

Or with `dplyr` utilizing `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(TYPE_OF_PROMOTION)) %>%
    mutate(counter2 = case_when(is.na(TYPE_OF_PROMOTION) ~ NA_integer_, 
                              TRUE ~ row_number())) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

---

or using `base R` with `rle`

```
with(df1, with(rle(!is.na(TYPE_OF_PROMOTION)), 
          sequence(lengths) * rep(NA^!values, lengths)))
#[1] NA  1  2  3 NA NA NA  1  2 NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Week = 11:20, TYPE_OF_PROMOTION = c(NA, "B", "B", 
"B", NA, NA, NA, "B", "B", NA), counter = c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("11", 
 "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: Just left with the curiousity whether it can be done outside data.table...

Comment: @Bullzeye. yes, it can be done, did you meant `base R`

Comment: @Bullzeye Included `base R` and `dplyr` based solutions

Comment: Marked as "answer" - much appreciated !!